# Date with Time zone in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

My requirement is to have "**YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.XXX [gmt offset[:tz name]]**" date format (ex: **20140425053117.694[+5.30:IST]**) for a Date field in Java.
I can achieve this simply using this SimpleDateFormat class which returns a **String** as output. But I want the output as a "**Date**" object with the above Pattern.

How can I achieve this, please help!!

Comment: Then keep it as a Date, and use SimpleDateFormat when you want to display it.

Comment: Friends I want this "YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.XXX [gmt offset[:tz name]]" format as a Date object and not all as a String data type because I use a library "OFX4J" in which it needs a Date object as input and it generates an Xml element which is of the above form I mentioned!!

Comment: Then you don't need to do anything, since OFX4J will format it correctly.

Comment: FYI, the new java.time package in Java 8 uses a similar format by default. This format is an extension of the standard ISO 8601, appending the time zone name. Example: `2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]`

Comment: OFX4J doesn't give me this "20140425053117.694[+5.30:IST]" format. It gives me this "20140306075536.012" format! It would be great if you can tell me if I can achieve the pattern that I want using OFX4J itslef! @nos

Comment: And hey Basil can't I achieve this in Java 7 or earlier?? I cannot use Java 8 now.@BasilBourque

Comment: @Lav Yes, there is a [project to backport JSR 310](http://www.threeten.org/) (the spec for java.time) to Java 7. I do not know anything about its success or progress. I believe you could build your desired String using Joda-Time library, by calling the `getZone` method on a DateTime object.

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Date` object encapsulates a `long` value that represents number of milliseconds since an epoch. In simple terms, you can think of `Date` class as a convenient way of storing a `long` number representing a date <strike>along with timezone information</strike>.

Whenever you want to display the date, you can format it any way, for example with `SimpleDateFormat`.

Prior to JDK 1.1, the `java.util.Date` could be used to parse and format dates. Starting from JDK 1.1 the parsing and formatting related methods of java.util.Date are deprecated.

Read more at Date class' [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) page

Comment: Correction: `java.util.Date` has NO internal timezone information and only refers to UTC timezone per specification while its `toString()`-method uses the system timezone for output.

Comment: To clarify Meno Hochschild's comment, the toString method applies the JVM's default time zone. Usually the JVM's default time zone is the same as the host operating system's time zone, but not necessarily. See [the doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault-java.util.TimeZone-).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's what you want:

```
SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
Date date = isoFormat.parse("2010-05-23T09:01:02");
```